# Bounding dimensions of Galois cohomology

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be the absolute Galois group of the rationals, and $V$ a finite dimensional $p$-adic representation.

Is there a way to provide a general bound on $H^i(G, V)$ in terms of $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}_p} V$? For $i=0$ the cohomology group is bounded by $\dim V$ trivially. I am particularly interested in $i=1,2$.

What if I assume $V$ is crystalline at $p$ and unramified everywhere else?

Comment: The absolute Galois group of the rationals has an element of order two, so it has infinite cohomological dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Is there a simple explanation why having an element of order 2 implies infinite cohomological dimension?

Comment: Also, corrected the question in accordance.

Comment: I would bet the question you want to ask is for $G$ the Galois group of the maximal extension unramified outside a finite set and that you want to consider continuous cohomology (then the answer is no, you cannot do that - the reason being that the dimension of a subspace of $H^1$ is bounded below by the order of vanishing of some $L$-functions, and that could be huge).

Comment: @Olivier where can I read more about this?

Comment: I would need to know your background to be able to give a really informative answer, but I guess you could worse than Autour des conjectures de Bloch-Kato (Fontaine/Perrin-Riou) in the volumes Motives.

Comment: Bellaiche's Clay summer school lectures on the Bloch--Kato conj are also a good starting point (perhaps a good warmup before you tackle Fontaine-Perrin-Riou).